# Buscar palabras dentro de un archivo

Tags: python

quiero saber como puedo buscar palabras dentro de un archivo

```
import sys
occurrences = 0
try:
 with open(sys.argv[1]) as f
```

Pero esto solo me busca letras en vez de palabras.
Gracias a todos por la

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable que has llamado `words` mejor se llamaría `line` ya que eso es realmente lo que contiene, puesto que `f.readlines()` te devuelve una lista de líneas.

Cuando haces `for w in words` estás iterando por una línea que es una cadena. Cuando iteras por una cadena lo que obtienes son las letras.

Si lo cambias a `for w in words.split()` entonces ya estarías iterando por palabras, dado que `split()` divide una cadena por los espacios y te retorna una lista con los trozos resultantes. Aún así esto no sirve para tu caso ya que los trozos que tendrías en `w` serían `"holayadios"` en la primera iteración y `"holahola"` en la segunda iteración. Y ya que luego comparas `w` con `sys.argv[2]` que presumo que es la palabra "hola", no te va a contar ninguna ocurrencia, ya que "holayadios" es distinto de "hola".

Podrías pensar en cambiar la comparación por `if sys.argv[2] in w`. Esto sigue sin funcionar del todo bien, ya que te contaría las palabras que contienen "hola" en interior, por lo que te contaría una vez "holayadios" y otra vez "holahola". El resultado sería 2 en lugar de 3 como tú quieres.

Se me ocurre la siguiente ***trampa horrible***. (EDIT: Ver al final versión mucho más razonable propuesta por @Dante S)

Divide el contenido del fichero por la cadena "hola", y cuenta cuántos trozos aparecen. Digamos que te salen N. Eso implica que "hola" apareció N-1 veces.

Comprobación. Dada la entrada `"holayadios holahola"`, el resultado de dividir por "hola" sería la siguiente lista:

```py
>>> "holayadios holahola".split("hola")
['', 'yadios ', '', '']
```

que tiene cuatro elementos, por lo que "hola" apareció 3 veces.

Usando esta idea tu código podría quedar así:

```
import sys
occurrences = 0
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
 for line in f:
    occurrences += len(line.split(sys.argv[2])) - 1
print("The word", sys.argv[2], "appeared", occurrences, "times in the file", sys.argv[1])
```

**Nota**, he quitado el `try` porque a fin de cuentas no había `except`, y también he quitado el `f.close()` porque no es necesario al trabajar con el contexto `with` (el fichero se cierra automáticamente al abandonar el contexto). He quitado también la variable intermedia `words` ya que puedes iterar directamente por `f` y cada iteración te da una línea.

### Otra versión

Mucho más razonable, propuesta por @Dante S. No sé en qué estaría pensando yo... `str.count()` te cuenta las apariciones de una subcadena dada, así que:

```
import sys
occurrences = 0
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
 for line in f:
    occurrences += line.count(sys.argv[2])
print("The word", sys.argv[2], "appeared", occurrences, "times in the file", sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Que tal si usas `cadena.count("hola")` en lugar de esa "trampa horrible"?

Comment: Pues va a ser que tienes razón! Con lo que me gustan a mi las trampas horribles! XD

Answer (score 0):

La función readlines crea un listado de todas las líneas de un archivo (En este caso si el archivo tiene una única línea "holayadios holahola", la lista creada será la siguiente:

```
['holayadios holahola']
```

Luego estás iterando por cada uno de los elementos y los comparas con la palabra que quieres buscar:

```
'hola' == 'holayadios holahola'
```

Como puedes ver, no son iguales los dos strings.

---

```
import sys

file = sys.argv[1]
word = sys.argv[2]

with open(file) as f:

    words = f.read()

    occurrences = words.count(word)

    print("The word", word, "appeared",
          occurrences, "times in the file", file)
    f.close()
```

En esta solución, words no es un listado de cada línea del txt sino que es un str 'holayadios holahola', luego utilizo el método **count** del string y le paso como argumento la palabra que quiero buscar, este método hace justamente lo que buscas: contar cuantas veces aparece un substring en un string